# How do I call a spring controller through plain javascript function

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

Note: I do not want ajax or jquery implementation because such approaches are already on stack. 
Please Help Soon.

Here is the code for reference

```
 <div class="col-lg-3  col-xs-12  ">
                        <div class="small-box bg-aqua" id="java" onclick="myFunc(this.id);">
                            <a class="small-box-footer"> JAVA </a>
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3><c:out value="${javaCount}"/></h3>  
                                <p>Java</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="icon" style="padding-top: 27px;"> <i
                                class="fa fa-book  ">
                                </i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

On click of above modal call's the below function

```
   function myFunc(id){
    alert(id)
    $('#').attr('action','${pageContext.request.contextPath}/viewSpecificBook?data='+ id);
    $('#').submit();
}
```

Now the above function should call the following spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="viewSpecificBook", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewSpecificBook()
{


}
```

After debugging I have noticed that the control is not forwarded to the spring but it reaches the javascript function.

Please Help!

Comment: Have you tried to debugging the rest api? Just open the rest controller url directly on browser, this would trigger GET request. If you place a debug point on controller, it should reach there.

Comment: have you checked? this https://dzone.com/articles/rich-web-application-with-spring-mvc-crud-demo-2

Comment: @ShivajiVarma I am not using rest.
I would appreciate if you could come up a solution by only using javascript.

Comment: @RohitPatil Spring Rest controller is nothing but Rest api controller.  `@RequestMapping(value="viewSpecificBook", method = RequestMethod.GET)` is specifying rest method type and url. URL will be something like `/rest_controler_value/request_mapping` i.e `/value_part_in_rest_controler/viewSpecificBook`

Comment: check this tutorial http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-rest-service-example-using-restcontroller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function myFunc(id){
window.location = 'your_url?data='+id;
}
```

It will also hit your controller. Just try this, it will work.